# Surprising NullPointerException when using ?:

Tags: java, conditional-operator, language-specifications

Here is a little oddity:

```
Integer oddity(boolean b1, boolean b2) {
  return b1 ? 0 : b2 ? 1 : null;
}
```

This will fail with a `NullPointerException` if `b1` and `b2` are false. But this:

```
Integer oddity(boolean b1) {
  return b1 ? 0 : null;
}
```

Does not throw an NPE when `b1` is false.

Why is this?

Comment: Nice find!  Further proof that boxing was a mistake ;)

Answer (score 2):

As you might imagine, the `NullPointerException` in the first case is as a result of implicit unboxing. This is all as described [in JLS Sec 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25); but the rules are complex, and have some tricky facets.

The surprising thing here is that this:

```
System.out.println(b ? 0 : null);
```

Is not the same as

```
Integer v = null;
System.out.println(b ? 0 : v);
```

- The conditional expression in the first case has type `Integer`: the `0` is boxed to `Integer.valueOf(0)`. Hence, this statement will complete normally, printing `0` or `null`.
- The conditional expression in the second case has type `int`: `v` is *unboxed* to `v.intValue()`. Hence, this statement will either print `0`, or fail with a `NullPointerException`.

So: the first example in the question is actually a combination of these two cases. Inserting the implicit boxing and unboxing, it becomes:

```
return Integer.valueOf(b1 ? 0 : (b2 ? Integer.valueOf(1) : null).intValue());
```

which can fail on the call to `intValue()`; whereas the second example in the question is:

```
return b1 ? Integer.valueOf(0) : null;
```

which will not fail.

---

If you want to return 0, 1 or null, the smallest change would be to box the `0` explicitly:

```
return b1 ? Integer.valueOf(0) : b2 ? 1 : null;
```

This looks awkward, because the 0 and 1 are differently represented. You could box the 1 explicitly too:

```
return b1 ? Integer.valueOf(0) : b2 ? Integer.valueOf(1) : null;
```

which works, but is verbose, and some well-meaning colleague (or you, when you come back to it some months later, having forgotten the reasons for the explicit boxing) will remove the boxing, because you don't need that, right?

Personally - having spent time recently looking at the conditional operator in some detail - I would opt to avoid it completely, and not risk falling foul of its curious type rules.

```
if (b1) {
  return 0;
} else if (b2) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return null;
}
```